# I assigned the role with grant select on table in my scheme to other user. What will be happened if I drop this table and recovered it via backup?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

Is the privilege recovers automatically or I need the grant this role again?

Answer (score 0):

Privilege will be recovered after you restore it from backup.

How do I know? I just tried it. So could have you.